# usb modem not detected

Tags: networking, usb-modem

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. New to Ubuntu.

Huawei E3131 detected as mass storage. Ejected it, nothing doing. 
Installed modem-manager, its not showing here as well.

This works with Windows, obviously with the Windows(only) setup.exe
cmd: lsusb shows 12d1:15ca as vendor and product ids.
If a Linux compatible script is available, so much the better. (For new users).
Hope someone could help. (I am new to Linux).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but **GNOME PPP** has solved it. It looks like your modem type is CDMA.

What you should do if your modem is CDMA:

1. Install `gnome-ppp` from Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Connect USB Modem.
3. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo gnome-ppp
   ```
4. Open Setup and select Detect button (try it 5-6 times if it cannot detect your modem, if still it can't detect  then reconnect your modem or restart OS).
5. If your modem is successfully detected, click Close and enter Username, password, dialup number.
6. If it can't connect, then try 5-6 times, if still it can't connect then reconnect modem or restart OS and go to 2nd point.
7. If it fails when "Waiting for prompt", then your *Username* or *password* or *Dial up number* is incorrect.

For other GSM modems use Sakis3G.